# Django does not send emails via smtp

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I'm trying to send a email via smtp using Django. When I try to send the email, I do not get any error, but my application does not respond and it keeps waiting on to send the email, but obviously it does not send nothing.

I have tried with smtp gmail and smtp hotmail, but it is not working. I have already checked my Windows firewall, and again it is not working. I have tried to send the email using Python shell but it does not send nothing.

I think that I have tried almost everything that I saw on the other posts here in Stack Overflow.

settings.py:

```
      EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
      EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
      EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
      EMAIL_PORT = 587
      EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@hotmail.com'
      EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
      SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

mails.py:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.template.loader import get_template
    from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

    class Mail:
    @staticmethod
    def send_complete_order(orden, user):
        subject = 'order sent'
        template = get_template('orders/mails/complete.html')
        content = template.render({
            'user': user
    })

    message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, 'Testing', 
                                     settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [user.email])

    message.attach_alternative(content, 'text/html')
    message.send()
```

views.py:

```
     @login_required(login_url='login')
     def complete(request):
         cart = get_or_create_cart(request)
         order = get_or_create_order(cart, request)

     if request.user.id != order.user_id:
        return redirect('carts:cart')

     order.complete()
     Mail.send_complete_order(order, request.user)

     destroy_cart(request)
     destroy_order(request)

     messages.success(request, "order complete")
     return redirect('index')
```

Comment: add your email sending django code

Comment: hi, i have just added the code.

Comment: Trying to send your own emails is generally unreliable anyway. Could you try MailChimp or MailGun etc?

Answer (score 0):

## Create a secure SSL context

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
try:
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_mail, port, context=context) as server2:
        server2.login(your_mail, passwort)
        server2.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, message.as_string())
        print("Successfully sent email")
```

Comment: hi, Albert. O thanks for sharing your code with me, but for me it does not work. its happening what i commented above.